# Implementation of NN scaling function to work with byte[3]

Tags: c++, pixel, scaling

This NN scaling function is created to work with integers and is pretty much integer-dependent.

```
public int[] resizePixels(int[] pixels,int w1,int h1,int w2,int h2) {
    int[] temp = new int[w2*h2] ;
    // EDIT: added +1 to account for an early rounding problem
    int x_ratio = (int)((w1<<16)/w2) +1;
    int y_ratio = (int)((h1<<16)/h2) +1;
    //int x_ratio = (int)((w1<<16)/w2) ;
    //int y_ratio = (int)((h1<<16)/h2) ;
    int x2, y2 ;
    for (int i=0;i<h2;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<w2;j++) {
            x2 = ((j*x_ratio)>>16) ;
            y2 = ((i*y_ratio)>>16) ;
            temp[(i*w2)+j] = pixels[(y2*w1)+x2] ;
        }                
    }                
    return temp ;
}
```

How do I set it to **work** with RGB trio instead?

Comment: I suppose you would start by changing the types of the first argument and the return value to something that represents your RGB data.  What exactly that would be depends on the form of data themselves, but possibly it would be `uint8_t[][3]`, or something similar.

Comment: Isn't it the same but using `w*h*3` ints instead of `w*h` only?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger, I'm having trouble imagining how the RGB data could be laid out that would make your suggestion work.  Even supposing that each color channel was `sizeof(int)` bytes wide, the scaling needs to be performed on a per-channel basis.

Comment: A usual way to store a multiple channel matrix is with an array of `w*h*c` elements (being `c` the number of channels). I think that's the memory layout OpenCV uses, for example. So each channel takes `w*h` elements and starts at address `base[w*h*i]`, for `i=0,1,2`. Your suggestion to use `type[][3]` is also valid, of course.